# WebServiceContext getting null in Stateless web service deployed on Weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic12c, stateless

My JAX WS web service is deployed on weblogic server 12. Its a ear file which contains war archive.
I used  @Resource WebServiceContext wsContxt; to get client IP.
When i deploy this WAR file on glassfish ,  WebServiceContext is working well. But it seems It  is not functioning on weblogic. Is there anything i have missed. Please advice.
Thanks in Advance,
Kevin.

EDIT:-

Problem solved after i re-construct the ear file as instructed in this site [enter link description here](https://metro.java.net/guide/ch02.html#weblogic-10)

But using WebServiceContext i can only get client IP , Username is getting null. See my code below.

```
MessageContext msgCtxt = wsCtxt.getMessageContext();
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)msgCtxt.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST); 
String clientIP = req.getRemoteAddr(); // Working
req.getUserPrincipal().getName() // Not Working
```

Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow i manage to get userid like below.

```
MessageContext msgCtxt = wsCtxt.getMessageContext();
Subject subj = SubjectAccessor.getRequesterSubject(msgCtxt);
Set set = subj.getPrincipals();
Iterator i = set.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   Principal p = (Principal) i.next();
   username = p.getName();
}
```